# How to validate json string has duplicate property

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a json string as below. How could I check whether this json has duplicate property "login".

```
 {
    "login": {
        "username": "any1",
        "password": "pass1"
    },
    "login": {
        "username": "any2",
        "password": "pass2"
    }
}
```

Could someone help me this case?

Comment: Can you talk us through **why** you want to validate this?

Answer (score 0):

This solution might not be elegant but should work.

1. Basically you can dump the contents into an array and sort it by key,  alphabetically.
2. Loop through your array.
3. Compare the current key with a temporary variable holding the previous key's name.
4. If the previous key and the current key matches, then you have a duplicate.